# Modal QDialog still allows timers to call slots?

Tags: qt, qdialog, qtimer

In my Qt program, I have modal `QDialogs` that are meant to halt everything and not continue execution of code until after it is dismissed. And it works for the function it's in--I put a breakpoint on the next line of code after `qDialog::exec()` and it doesn't break until after I dismiss the dialog.

However, there is a `QTimer` connected to a slot on its timeout, and it will continue to go even when the modal dialog is up and execute the code in its slot.

I suppose I could stop the timer before showing the `modal dialog`. However, there may be cases when the dialog is in a totally different class than the timer. Is there a way to truly halt execution of the program until the `QDialog` is dismissed?

Example:

```
QTimer* pTestTimer = new QTimer( this );
connect( pTestTimer , SIGNAL( timeout() ), this, SLOT( timerSlot() ) );

//Slot code elsewhere
void cMyClass::deleteMeTimerSlot()
{
    qDebug() << "See me during modal?";
}

//starting a modal dialog
pTestTimer->start( 1000 );

QDialog* pModalDlg = new QDialog( this, Qt::Dialog | Qt::FramelessWindowHint     | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint );

pModalDlg->setModal(true);
pMOdalDlg->exec();
```

Output still shows "See me during modal?" while in `exec()`;

Answer (score 0):

> I suppose I could stop the timer before showing the modal dialog.
>   However, there may be cases when the dialog is in a totally different
>   class than the timer.

Yes, you can do operate with all the timers accessible within the parent context (it seems like you look for generic solution).

```
// Halt all the timers within parent context.
// If all the timers have parent maybe the top app widget pointer
// should be used for parentObj
QList<QTimer*> listOfTimers = parentObj->findChildren<QTimer*>(
   QString(), Qt::FindChildrenRecursively);
for(QTimer* pTimer : listOfTimers)
   pTimer->stop();
```

> Is there a way to truly halt execution of the program until the QDialog is dismissed?

Unless you mean stop all the threads: No, QDialog is part of the program and does not imply halting any execution but modal dialog runs in own event loop and only prevents user from operating the other program UI. I suppose you can probably restart all stopped timers after exiting the modal dialog.

```
pModalDlg->exec();

// restart all the timers within parent context
for(QTimer* pTimer : listOfTimers)
   pTimer->start();
```

You can also peek at Qt source code (at QDialog and event loop it uses) and create your own sophisticated dialog class with very specific event loop for it.